# Testing angular directive with jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

Having a little trouble testing an Angular directive.

Essentially I just have a file input and the directive adds a class to the outer div to show the input has been dragged over.

Now this works fine in the application but just struggling to confirm the behaviour works in the test:

Directive:

```
angular.module('mymodule')
.directive('fileDrop', () => {
  const link = (scope, elem) => {
    const input = elem.find('input[type="file"]');
    const dragEnter = (e) => {
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
      elem.addClass('file_drop--over');
    };
    const dragLeave = (e) => {
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
      elem.removeClass('file_drop--over');
    };
    input.bind('dragenter', dragEnter);
    input.bind('dragleave', dragLeave);
  };
  return {
    'restrict': 'A',
    link,
  };
});
```

test:

```
describe('fileDrop', () => {
  let compile;
  let scope;
  let fileDropElem;

  const getCompiledElement = () => {
    const element = '<div class="file_drop"><input type="file" /></div>';
    const compiledElement = compile(element)(scope);
    scope.$digest();
    return compiledElement;
  };

  beforeEach(() => {
    module('mymodule');

    inject(($compile, $rootScope) => {
      compile = $compile;
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
    });

    fileDropElem = getCompiledElement();
  });


  it('should add file_drop--over class on drag enter', () => {
    fileDropElem.find('input[type="file"]').trigger('dragenter');
    expect(fileDropElem.hasClass('file_drop--over')).toEqual(true);
  });
});
```

The test fails because the class isn't added

Comment: Shouldn't it be triggerHandler instead of trigger?

Comment: Ah yes I could use that too I guess. I think the issue is that it is not triggering the dragEnter function in the directive. Tried adding breakpoint there and nothing happens so maybe there is an issue with how the test has hooked the directive up. Finding directives to be harder to test in Angular than the other pieces

Comment: Turns out I was just making a stupid mistake and not attaching the directive, so the above example will work but with the change to the string that gets compiled to include the directive:
<div class="file_drop" file-drop><input type="file" /></div>

Comment: Oh, I missed that too! Happens way more than I would like to admit.